# Can the code running on Rpi1 run on Rpi2?

Tags: pi-2

Can the code running on the Raspberry pi Model 1 run on the Model 2?

Comment: The short answer is yes

Answer (score 2):

Yes, code on a Pi 1 will work Pi 2.

The only cases I can think of which would cause it not to work are these:

### GPIO

The Pi B+, Pi 2, Pi 3, and Pi Zero have extra GPIO pins, so if you try to run code for those pins on the Pi 1, it will not work.

### USB Slave Mode

The Pi Zero is the only model Pi that can be run in USB slave mode, so running code on another Pi that has to do with this would not work.

---

The only thing concerning the Pi 2 and the Pi 1 are the extra GPIO pins, other than that, you should be ok.

Comment: Beat me too it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In short, yes. Code from the other Pi models will also work on the Pi 2.

However, the long answer is, in some cases code such as `pifm` will not run on the pi 2, as is, because the GPIO addresses are different. 
***See COMMENT***
Obviously C code *compiled* on b+ into an *executable* will **not** run on the Pi 2 because it is a different architecture. It must be recompiled on the Pi 2. 
Python scripts and some other languages that use interpreters however will work regardless as long as the interpreter is installed on the computer you are running the script on.

Comment: *"Obviously C code compiled on b+ into an executable will not run on the Pi 2 because it is a different architecture."* -> **Is false.**  The ARMv7 ISA from the Pi 2 is backward compatible with the ARMv6 ISA from previous models.   It may be true the other way around but it actually depends on the OS used, since it is the toolchain that matters (e.g., since Raspbian is the same on all models, any code  compiled on it will run on any Pi).

Comment: @goldilocks Thanks for the info.Learn something new everyday :-)